# Howto skip over cpio archive when multiple cpio archives are concatenated

Tags: 18.04, initramfs

When doing a `update-initramfs -u` that will eventually call `/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs` the `__TMPEARLYCPIO` variable will point to data that is *prepended* to the final initramfs. For an AMD system it seems to consist of an uncompressed cpio archive with only one file `kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin` in.  After the first cpio section the real initramfs starts, however because of the prepended section the simple `zcat /boot/initramfsfile | cpio --extract` now doesnt work any more.

- how can I strip ofer the first prepended cpio? How can I calculate the size of one cpio archive?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266089/extracting-concatenated-cpio-archives) `dracut`'s skipcpio does the trick: [skipcpio](https://github.com/dracutdevs/dracut/tree/master/skipcpio). 
I can then use it like this:

```
skipcpio /boot/initrd.img-4.12.0-rc6-custom > initrd.img-4.12.0-rc6-custom.real
zcat initrd.img-4.12.0-rc6-custom.real | cpio --extract
```

`skipcpio` skips over the first (noncompressed) ASCII cpio block and prints the rest. If two firmware blobs are prepended this has to be run two times.